# When trying to drill down on my RadGrid.Net2 RadGrid control, I get "Parent table relations set, but no correspoding data-key name found"

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

For simplicity's sake, here's the markup code in my aspx/webform:

```
    <radG:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1"
        OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"
        OnDetailTableDataBind="RadGrid1_DetailTableDataBind"
        EnableAJAXLoadingTemplate="True"
        runat="server"
        EnableAJAX="True">
        <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="ID" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" DataType="System.String" UniqueName="ID" SortExpression="ID" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="ID">
                </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="Name" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="Name" SortExpression="Name" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Name">
                </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="Description" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="Description" SortExpression="Description" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Description">
                </radG:GridBoundColumn>
            </Columns>
            <DetailTables>
                <radG:GridTableView Skin="WebBlue" SkinsPath="~/admin/os/RadControls/Grid/Skins/" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="Normal" DataKeyNames="ID" Width="100%" runat="server" Name="ClientDetail" GridLines="Horizontal" BorderColor="White">
                    <ParentTableRelation>
                        <radG:GridRelationFields DetailKeyField="ID" MasterKeyField="NameID" />
                    </ParentTableRelation>
                    <Columns>
                        <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="ID" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="ID" SortExpression="ID" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="ID">
                        </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                        <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="Name" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="Name" SortExpression="Name" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Name">
                        </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                    </Columns>
                </radG:GridTableView>
            </DetailTables>
        </MasterTableView>
    </radG:RadGrid>
```

And very simply, here is the code-behind:

```
    protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object source, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.IsFromDetailTable)
        {
            RadGrid1.MasterTableView.DataSource = GetMasterDataSet();
        }
    }

    private DataSet GetMasterDataSet()
    {
        var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=localhost;Database=RadGridTest;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from names (nolock)", connection);
        var dataSet = new DataSet();

        adapter.Fill(dataSet);

        return dataSet;
    }

    protected void RadGrid1_DetailTableDataBind(object sender, GridDetailTableDataBindEventArgs e)
    {
        var parentItem = e.DetailTableView.ParentItem;

        if (parentItem.Edit)
        {
            return;
        }

        var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=localhost;Database=RadGridTest;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(@"select id, name from classes where nameid = " + parentItem["ID"].Text, connection);
        var dataSet = new DataSet();

        adapter.Fill(dataSet);

        e.DetailTableView.DataSource = dataSet;
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took off the following piece of code and it worked like a charm:

```
                <ParentTableRelation>
                    <radG:GridRelationFields DetailKeyField="ID" MasterKeyField="NameID" />
                </ParentTableRelation>
```